# How can I efficiently import all global variables from external globals.js file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, import, external, var

I need to import hundreds of global variables from global.js to the main.js.
Does JavaScript have an efficient method to import all exports from that file at once, without importing them one-by-one?
I could import them all as a large object e.g. `g` and address them like `g.myVar1`, but I prefer to avoid that.

Even importing one-by-one esbuild gave me the error: "imports are immutable in JS" so only global constants can be imported, not variables.
So apparently there is no solution to this question...

Comment: Can you please update your question with an input, expected output and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `import * as g from './global.js';` maybe?

Comment: Tangential, but I’d also ask, and hopefully address, why there are hundreds of globals.

Comment: @Diego D  I have explicitly stated that I want to avoid that.

Comment: @Dave Newton - unoptimized code of 10000 lines. Before I fully optimize it, I need to make it readable first, so I'm splitting it into external files.

Comment: @Diego  - "I could import them all as a large object e.g 'g' and address them like g.myVar1, but I prefer to avoid that."  See?

Comment: I see.. and I still don't get what you mean. You prefer to avoid using a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dllb But that's how JS works :shrug: Imports/exports treat external files as a module and need to be treated as such. You could so something horrible like iterate and hang on `global` *(or whatever it is, I forget)* but that's even worse.

Comment: @Dave  Newton - apparently it's impossible to change an imported variable in JS (ironically), so this is futile any way - see my edit of the question.

Comment: The idiotic (robotic) "Heretic Monkey" removed the 'EDIT' from the question, and so the second part appears as a self-contradiction [facepalm].

Comment: @dllb "Edit" tagging is rarely helpful; it wasn't particularly helpful here either. Also they're not an idiot. I'm not sure what "change an imported variable" means (or why it's ironic, but that's a separate thread).

Comment: @Dave Newton - Edit denotes revision, and it is meant to separate it from the previous part, e.g as a second thought, or something you found out at a later time, which might be correcting what was previously written. So it was definitely idiotic to remove it, render the text as self-contradicting, and confuse the readers.

Comment: @dllb I'm aware of what the word means, but thanks. YYMV, seems pretty :shrug:-worthy to me but you do you :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using nodejs then this is an option.

global variables are implicitly declared when imported as long as they were not declared with var, const or let

e.g.

```
//global.js
myGlobalVariable = 'my value'

//app.js
require('./global.js')
console.log(myGlobalVariable) //output - 'my value'
```

Comment: Can their values be changed in app.js?
Also, can this work with a bundler, eg esbuild?

Comment: yes, the values can be changed to any data type the only consideration, not that i would expect you need to do this but if you decide to redeclare the same variable in app.js with const & let, will throw an error, if you decide to use var keyword it won't throw an error but your variable before being redeclared or having its value updated in app.js will be undefined, this is due to JS hoisting. i haven't tested with a bundler unfortunately

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me 'undefined'.

Comment: can you provide an example of the code you're trying this on? also, have you ensured you've removed any instance of the declaration key words const, let & var for the variable from the file you're importing from e.g. globals.js.

Comment: It works, thanks! After removing the "var" from each global variable, everything worked (at first glance, it seems weird). I've seen and used 'require' before (on local server code), but never thought I could use it in my main code.

Comment: The downside is that documentation via /** */ does not pass, and hovering the mouse over a global value imported with this method says "any" like it is undefined, but it works.